# Why does TreePlot ignore the vertex labels in a TreeGraph argument?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, labeling, documentation, trees

Example (watch the vertex labels):

```
aTree = TreeGraph[{"a" -> "b", "a" -> "c"}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
VertexList[aTree]
(* {a, b, c} *)
```

...but

```
TreePlot[aTree, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrgggggggggggggggggggghhhhh!!!!

Is there some justification for `TreePlot`'s ignoring the names/labels in the original `TreeGraph`?

(It's perversity like this that makes me most resent *Mathematica*'s laconic documentation style...)

BTW, eventually, after almost 2 hours of searching the documentation and trial-and-error, I figured out that

```
TreePlot[Rule @@@ EdgeList[aTree], DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

will do what I want.  This is to emphasize that this question is less about getting the right output from `TreePlot` than about avoiding monumental wastes of time like this one in the future.  (E.g. a clarification regarding the relationship between the various `Graph`-related functions may do the job.)

Comment: @kglr For those like myself who read questions ordered by recent activity, edits to a couple dozen in a short time span has a disconcerting way of burying things that might be of interest. Is there a compelling need for so much editing of past posts?

Comment: Sorry @Daniel. Didn't realize  questions with my edits filled up the top page. Frustrated by difficulties of  searching for posts that I am sure I have seen recently, I have settled on filtering by tags --  and. more often, I was able to find what I searched if I used multiple tags. I noticed, however, that many posts lacked obvious tags.  That's why  I have been editing tags last few days . I will stop for now. Sorry again.

Comment: @kglr Was not sure why you were editing. Adding tags is of course very useful. I guess if it could just be not quite so frequently...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`TreePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreePlot.html) predates [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html).  Only in version 10 was it updated to handle `Graph` according to the documentation.  Since `Graph` supports more advanced functionality than `TreePlot` it is unsurprising that only a subset is supported by the latter, and `VertexLabels` is not supported.  If you convert the `Graph` to an older, more basic format `TreePlot` will work:

```
TreePlot[Rule @@@ EdgeList[aTree], VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

Yes, it would be nice if this were handled automatically.  However other parts of the system that are in greater need of attention (IMO) still await update, so again I am not suprised.

Answer (score 3):

An update for the record. The same situation described by Mr. Wizard appears to be the case in version 11.2. However, using Graph with `GraphLayout->"LayeredEmbedding"` can achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

#### *Why*

The why part is explained nicely in [this answer by Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/188943/125) in a closely related Q/A:

- ***In 11.3 (and probably all the way back to at least 10.0),*** **GraphPlot** ***also takes*** **Graph** ***expressions as input. But it handles*** **Graph*****s by converting them to a matrix (not a rule list!) first. Thus the vertex names are lost, and it will use vertex indices instead.***

#### *A hidden option* ("VertexNames") *as a workaround:*

```
Row[{aTree = TreeGraph[{"a" -> "b", "a" -> "c"}, VertexLabels -> "Name"],
  TreePlot[aTree, VertexLabeling -> True, "VertexNames" -> VertexList[aTree]]}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]