# Why Does GraphPlot mislabel Vertices from a Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

A very peculiar thing is happening when I wrap a Graph with GraphPlot. The picture below shows the correct vertex labeling. However, GraphPlot changes the vertex labeling! Am I misusing this function or is this something I should report to Wolfram? I'm running version 11.0.1.0.

Below is some code to reproduce the issue (but with a simpler graph).

```
{gph = Graph[{2 -> 1, 5 -> 0, 7 -> 6, 8 -> 7, 10 -> 8, 0 -> 2, 2 -> 3,
 3 -> 4, 5 -> 10, 8 -> 9}, VertexLabels -> "Name"],
GraphPlot[gph, VertexLabeling -> True]}
```

Interestingly enough, using a built-in function (like KaryTree) yields expected results:

```
{KaryTree[15, VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
GraphPlot[KaryTree[15], VertexLabeling -> True]}
```

My work-around is using Graph and formatting it exactly how I want, but I would like to understand why the vertex labeling is incorrect!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GraphPlot` supports inputs in several different formats.  Originally, it took either a list of `Rule`s or an adjacency matrix.  With a rule-list input, it displays the vertex labels you would expect.  But the adjacency matrix does not contain information about vertex names. Thus with a matrix input, it uses vertex *indices* (not names) for labelling.

In 11.3 (and *probably* all the way back to at least 10.0), `GraphPlot` also takes `Graph` expressions as input. But it handles `Graph`s by converting them to a matrix (not a rule list!) first. Thus the vertex names are lost, and it will use vertex indices instead.

Workaround: convert the graph to a rule list yourself.

```
GraphPlot[Rule @@@ EdgeList@gph, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 DirectedEdges -> True, Method -> "LayeredDrawing"]
```

[image]

Comment: One of SW's Twitch videos showed that `GraphPlot` is being updated for version 12.0, so you can expect this to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach: Use `VertexList[g]` as the option value for the undocumented option `"VertexNames"` in `GraphPlot`.

```
el = {2 -> 1, 5 -> 0, 7 -> 6, 8 -> 7, 10 -> 8, 0 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 10, 8 -> 9};

gph = Graph[el, ImageSize -> 300, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium, VertexStyle -> White];

Row @ {gph, 
  GraphPlot[gph, ImageSize -> 300, VertexLabeling -> True, 
    "VertexNames" -> VertexList[gph]]}
```

[image]

**Note:** This approach works for versions older than 12.0. For versions 12.0+, use the function `` GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy `` to access the older `GraphPlot` functionality.